# URL parameters returns null

Tags: javascript, url, parameters

I have stumbled across this issue and hope I can get some inputs here on what could be the cause.
I have a URL with some GET parameters as follows:

`www.test.com/test.jsp?serial=Id123:true;Id456:true;Id789:false;&session=1234567&userId=test`

I then extract the parameter to make a REST call

```
   const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
   console.log(window.location.search);
   console.log(params.get("serial"));
   console.log(params.get("session"));
   console.log(params.get("userId"));
   const url = new URL("service/resources/query?", document.baseURI).href;
   fetch(url + params.toString())
```

I'd say half of the time my REST call would fail due to session and userId parameters being cut off.  Instead, I'm seeing this in my browser

```
www.test.com/test.jsp?serial=Id123:true
```

And my console print out would show

```
?serialNum=ZD0222:True
Id123:True
null
null
```

Any suggestions on why this happens and how I can write differently here?

**Additional note** - could the semicolon be the cause here?  I noticed that url only show first value of the first parameter.

Comment: _"due to session and userId parameters being cut off"_ Where? Do they get cut off when sending the request from the browser (look in your Network tab), or when receiving them on the server? Because it looks like there is nothing wrong in what you showed us. I tried it, everything looks fine (appart from the typos `serial/serialNum` and `session/sessionId` that you `console.log`)

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed the typo.  It doesn't happen all the time but I would say about 50% of the time that the request got cut off.

Comment: How do I check from the Network tab?  The url above would open a new browser and when I can get to Network tab, I don't see anything there.

Answer (score 0):

I think your window.location.search is not what you expect.
Looks good when I explicitly define the URL.

```js
const url = new URL("http://www.test.com/test.jsp?serial=Id123:true;Id456:true;Id789:false;&session=1234567&userId=test");
const params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
console.log(url.search);
console.log(params.get("serialNum"));
console.log(params.get("sessionId"));
console.log(params.get("userId"));
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. The url in my case is dynamic so I can't explicitly define there.  I have to use window.location.search to give me the current url. It doesn't happen all the time but I would say at least 50% of the time that my REST failed because the parameters got cut off.

Answer (score 0):

I would take another direction, maybe something like

```js
const url = 'http://www.test.com/test.jsp?serial=Id123:true;Id456:true;Id789:false;&session=1234567&userId=test',
  matches = url.match(/([&?](\w*)=([^?&]*))/g),
  res = matches.reduce((acc, el)=> {
    const sub = el.match(/[&?](.*)=(.*)/)
    acc[sub[1]] = sub[2]
    return acc
  }, {})
console.log(res)
```

Please note: that function is not dealing with many edge cases, but maybe can inspire You to find an acceptable way to get what You need.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have colon ( : ) in your URL, its considered as an invalid character. You can use colon only in special cases like specifying port number or in 'http://', etc.